# What is the word for lack of fashion sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word for people lacking practical fashion sense?

A typical definition could be:

> *something people wear which they think is trendy but actually doesn't suit them and looks awkward*

Comment: There are probably about 50 such words, 45 of which will signal that you have no fashion sense if you use them (especially among young people).

Comment: @HotLicks most of them insulting...

Comment: Maybe '*unfashionable*', or '*tasteless*'? you may find [this](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unfashionable) useful.

Comment: Your title and question ask for something different than your example definition.

Comment: @Jim Not really. OP asked for a word describing a lack of fashion sense. The proposed definition alludes to a person who lacks a fashion sense because they wear clothes that don't suit them and look awkward.

Comment: @AleksandrH - No. The proposed definition is “something people wear...” the title is about lack of fashion sense.  They are related in that a person who lacks fashion sense might wear that thing that looks awkward, but they are not the same.

Comment: How about "**dowdy**", or any of its synonyms? Often reserved for women, it describes someone who dresses very plainly, with little colour, and with no sense of fashion or style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are ***tacky***.  [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tacky)

> Lacking style or good taste; tawdry: tacky clothes.....
>
> ostentatious and vulgar

Tacky can also mean cheaply made, shoddy, dowdy, but a person can look tacky even wearing well made and expensive clothes if the separate pieces don't "go" together or if the clothes don't fit well (especially if they are too tight) or if the whole effect looks overdone.  For example, dripping with diamonds while wearing jeans and a T-shirt would be tacky for most people.  But some people can wear anything and look great.  Most of us are not so fortunate.